# TH cell to show 0% 25% 50% 75% 100% filled

Tags: html, css

I need to visualize the 0%..100% in the th cell and I would like to have it spaced to fill the how cell, and secondly it would be nice to have a line go all the way down the column to correspond with the colored bars I already have.  Thanks

Here is the beginning of my table. I need to have the  column with the percentages to actually go on the 25%, 50%, and 75% corresponding space of the column.

```
echo "<table border ='1'>"; echo "<tr><th>Application Affected</th><th>Application Availability</th><th>0% 25% 50% 75%100%</th><th>Number of Incidents</th>;
```

Comment: I was able to get the affect I needed using &nbsp.  the whitespace was getting eaten.  Sorry for the poorly worded question to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
   <th><div style="width: 25%; background: red">&nbsp;</div></th>
</tr>
```

Don't stretch cells, as that'll throw off all the other cells in the same column in the table. Stretch something INSIDE a cell instead.